# How do you design an aggregation framework for large datasets?

Tags: sql, ruby, database, database-design

I have a large dataset of incoming messages and what I want to do is provide aggregated statistics for each message owner, such as rate of messages per day, week, last two weeks, and year. The aggregations can be simple, such as a word count, or more complex, such as keywords used...either way, I want to -- in an organized fashion -- precalculate and store these aggregations so that when I do something like:

```
Person.word_count_last_10_days
```

-- that this query isn't run on the entire message archive database, but pulls from a table of precalculated aggregations...something like:

```
SELECT SUM(value) from aggregations
WHERE 
     category = "word_count" AND 
     timeframe = "day" AND date > "2013-05-18" AND date < "2013-05-28" AND 
     person_id = 42
GROUP BY person_id
```

And aggregations of larger timeframes, such as "year", would simply count up all the days that make up that year.

The overall objective is to decouple the analytics browsing from the massive message archive. For the most part, there's no reason for the analytics system to actually query the message archive, if the aggregations table contains all the data needed.

This strikes me as a very common usecase...it doesn't matter whether it's done through Hadoop or through non-parallel processing...so I was wondering if there was already a framework/wrapper/design-methodology that provides some convention for this, rather writing one completely from scratch? I'm using Ruby but language doesn't matter, I'm just interested in whatever frameworks/wrappers (in any language) that have already been conceived.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into OLAP/cubes for this kind of work.

Here is an open source OLAP server: http://mondrian.pentaho.com/

The idea is that with a cube you can set up pre-processed aggregations and then run them and afterwards the results can be queried quickly.

The MDX language is the equivalent of SQL for cubes - and it has a pretty steep learning curve - but some of the basic stuff should be easy to handle out of the box.

It takes a bit of reading to get up to speed on cubes in general. Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube.

It is well worth it for pre-processed aggregations.